# Rear derailleur mounting bolt or hanger thread stripped?

Tags: derailleur-hanger

Having some issue with my SRAM X01 Eagle rear derailleur mounting to the frame idk it won't bolt in with my torque wrench it's very loose? When it comes to drivetrain stuff I'm not experienced enough working with it seems simple issue but idk maybe the bolt is stripped? Or the hanger on the frame is stripped ? Any help appreciated thanks trying to avoid taking to a bike shop.

[image]

[image]

I think I got it set up right with the tab lined up with hanger and the B-screw

[image]

Comment: Mounting looks OK, b-screw washer is in the correct position relative to the hanger. What do you mean by 'it's very loose'? Can you tighten the bolt to spec torque setting or does it keep spinning?

Comment: Just keeps spinning that's why I was wondering if the threads we're stripped

Comment: You may be able to bodge this with a metal-epoxy or some permanent thread locker, but in reality replacing the hanger is going to be the "right" fix.  The bolt looks better than the hanger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on one of your photos, it appears the first few threads of the derailleur hanger hole are stripped. There should be threads present where that silvery smoothness is just inside the hole.  There are a few solutions to this problem.  The simplest would be retapping the hole.  This requires a Tap that will reform the proper thread size of 10mm x 1mm (that refers to a 10mm major diameter hole with 1mm pitched threads).  Park tools call the tool used to do this [TAP10](https://www.parktool.com/product/frame-tap-tap-10).  Hit the hyperlink to view the listing.

The Park Tool website also has a few interesting articles regarding issues, techniques, how to's regarding threading and fasteners on bicycles. [Basic Thread Concepts](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/basic-thread-concepts) will shine a lot of light on your problem.

BTW--welcome to Stack Exchange!  Based on your username, you may be my neighbor--a fellow Iowan at any rate.  Hope you can get that Eagle flying real soon.

Comment: Argenti's advice to obtain a new derailleur mounting bolt should be followed as well.

Comment: surely a replacement hanger is the better option? Cheaper than the tool or the labor to retap it.

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus From memory (I'm travelling and wishing to limit my data) it appeared that the hangar was part of the frame, and if so, wouldn't that limit the solutions? Agree replacement would be better and around the same to less cost.

Comment: Yea that's my next question how the hell do I remove the hanger from this type frame its clearly not bolt on like I noticed most in other tutorial take a t25 torque to remove it :-/

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus

Comment: Any help from either @Jeff

Comment: @Iowamtb87 post how to remove hanger as a new question, your comment here is won’t be seen by many people. Include a good photo of where the hanger bolts on.

Answer (score 2):

If the bolt spins in the hanger the threads are indeed stripped. The threads on the bolt don't look too badly damaged, so the hanger is where the threads are properly stripped out.

The tops of the threads on teh bolt look a bit worn to me - possible from spinning around inside the damaged hanger threads. I'd replace both the hanger and bolt as a precaution.

Comment: Ok damn that's a bummer i just bought the bike off pinkbike but it's always hard to tell if something was wrong from previous owner and maybe it was my fault mounting it when I got it ... I added a better photo of the hanger

Comment: Pic of the hanger is not properly focussed on the thread itself but I can immediately tell it's damaged

Comment: Ok well thanks for the feedback .. how much will that cost for replacement of hanger and bolt for Sram X01 Eagle

Comment: Devinci Spartan

Comment: @Iowamtb87 Not very expensive, few tens of $

Comment: The hanger will usually be specific to the frame, rather than the derailleur. You can either find a retailer selling the brand of bike to replace the hanger with an original one (provided that the brand keeps them in stock. The alternative is to browse the selection from [Wheels Manufacturing](https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/all-derailleur-hangers.html) who make a replacement hanger for just about every bike from the past two or three decades. Theirs are just as good as the originals, so don't stress about it being a third party component.